# Pidgin for XMPP -- SSL Handshake failed

Tags: ssl, xmpp, pidgin, ubuntu-18.04

I installed the latest Ubuntu 18.04 and am trying to connect to our in-house XMPP server (which is quite old and I have no access to) with Pidgin like I used to.

But I'm unable to connect... Getting an `SSL Handshake Failed` error.

This is what I get in the debug window:

`(10:37:11) account: Connecting to account d.goosens@%%SERVER_NAME%%/Spark 2.6.3.
(10:37:11) connection: Connecting. gc = 0x55e3f7cdca10
(10:37:11) dnsquery: Performing DNS lookup for %%SERVER_IP%%
(10:37:11) dnsquery: IP resolved for %%SERVER_IP%%
(10:37:11) proxy: Attempting connection to %%SERVER_IP%%
(10:37:11) proxy: Connecting to %%SERVER_IP%%:5222 with no proxy
(10:37:11) proxy: Connection in progress
(10:37:11) proxy: Connecting to %%SERVER_IP%%:5222.
(10:37:11) proxy: Connected to %%SERVER_IP%%:5222.
(10:37:11) jabber: Sending (d.goosens@%%SERVER_NAME%%/Spark 2.6.3): <?xml version='1.0' ?>
(10:37:11) jabber: Sending (d.goosens@%%SERVER_NAME%%/Spark 2.6.3): <stream:stream to='%%SERVER_NAME%%' xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0'>
(10:37:11) jabber: Recv (177): <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><stream:stream xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client" from="%%SERVER_NAME%%" id="a1c57c52" xml:lang="en" version="1.0">
(10:37:11) jabber: Recv (486): <stream:features><starttls xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"></starttls><mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><mechanism>DIGEST-MD5</mechanism><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism><mechanism>ANONYMOUS</mechanism><mechanism>CRAM-MD5</mechanism></mechanisms><compression xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/compress"><method>zlib</method></compression><auth xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/iq-auth"/><register xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/iq-register"/></stream:features>
(10:37:11) jabber: Sending (d.goosens@%%SERVER_NAME%%/Spark 2.6.3): <starttls xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls'/>
(10:37:11) jabber: Recv (50): <proceed xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"/>
(10:37:11) nss: Handshake failed  (-12279)
(10:37:11) connection: Connection error on 0x55e3f7cdca10 (reason: 5 description: SSL Handshake Failed)
(10:37:11) account: Disconnecting account d.goosens@%%SERVER_NAME%%/Spark 2.6.3 (0x55e3f700e310)
(10:37:11) connection: Disconnecting connection 0x55e3f7cdca10
(10:37:11) connection: Destroying connection 0x55e3f7cdca10
(10:37:12) util: Writing file prefs.xml to directory /home/dgoosens/.purple
(10:37:12) util: Writing file /home/dgoosens/.purple/prefs.xml`

*(replaced SERVER_NAME and SERVER_IP)*

Tried every possible account setting... but nothing seems to work...

Any suggestions ?

Comment: This is a non-programming question which belongs on Super User. I suggest posting your question there, and getting a packet capture of the SSL handshake using tcpdump or wireshark. Good luck!

Comment: Sorry... You're right...  Moved it to SU >> https://superuser.com/questions/1319751/pidgin-for-xmpp-ssl-handshake-failed

Answer (score 0):

I have solve the problem like this:

Modules -> NSS settings ->

Min version: 1.0
Max version: 1.3 (max available)

And check *all* crypto modules.

[See my screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHjQV.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHjQV.jpg)

WBR, Leonid Kaganov lleo@lleo.me